# PropertyChanged remains null

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have following textbox binding:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Auslastungskapazität1" Text="{Binding Kapazität, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,5,5" FontSize="16" ></TextBlock>
```

MainViewModel Class:

```
class MainViewModel: ZuliefererStandortListe,  IDropTarget, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int Kapazität {
        get { return _kapazität1Ausgelastet; }
        set {
            if (this._kapazität1Ausgelastet != value)
                _kapazität1Ausgelastet = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Kapazität");
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

DataContext is the in the MainWindow Constructor as

```
Kapazität.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

If I change Kapazität the int get changed and the OnPropertyChanged() method gets called. However "PropertyChanged" remains null and therefore the Textbox Binding doesn't get updated.

Comment: What is `Kapazität` in the MainWindow constructor? Looks odd, you should set `this.DataContext` or just `DataContext`. As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Text Binding is pointless. It has no effect here. German identifier names, especially with umlauts, also look odd.

Comment: I changed the umlauts, thx. I tried to declare the datacontext for the Kapazitaet property in the MainWindow. Maybe I understood something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Either set the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` itself:

```
Auslastungskapazität1.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

...or of any of its parent elements, such as for example the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```